# Some data is generated each 10 min on my 24h/24 running PC. What is the best way for my website to get this data?

Tags: web, api

Some data is generated each 10 min on my 24h/24 running PC. I want to find a way for my website to get this data. The data in question is only 10 lines of text.

I know I can host a linux instance to do so but I have a spare computer to use. And I want it to be free.
My first thought was to implement an API on the computer, but there is a security risk.
My second thought is to post the data to pastebin. Then read and get the data from my website.

What is the best solution to implement this logic ?

Comment: How about reversing this and having your computer post the data to your website instead? Would get rid of pesky NAT issues at the same time.

Comment: @r_ahlskog Smart. So do you suggest I make a POST request from my PC to an endpoint in my website backend ?

Comment: Dropbox or any other cloud backup solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I would turn it around so that I have my PC do a POST to my website. Doing that makes it easier by letting you manage several problems by not having them to begin with.

- Your website has a fixed address while home PC is probably assigned address by DHCP
- Avoids issues with NAT, either your own or fatally CG-NAT imposed by ISP
- Avoids getting half done data by letting the PC POST when it is ready.

Of course this requires that you can add such a thing to your website, which would basically be an endpoint. I would also stick TLS and authentication on it since Let's Encrypt is free and it would fix the problem with bots finding and posting random garbage for you.

Comment: This is clear. I'll do that. Thank you @r_ahlskog